# Why is the British passport the most valuable despite colonization?

Tags: uk, visas-on-arrival, visa-free-entry

I was checking out Wikipedia and I could see a [British passport entitles to visa-free or visa-on-arrival for 173 countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_British_citizens) despite colonization by the British. While USA ranks 2nd with 172 countries. Why?

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "colonization" in this context, nor on what it should have to do with current visa policies.

Comment: Also, since I think this is really more about international relations than travel, it might be better on http://politics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Why "despite" colonization? Seems likely to me that part of the independence process would include better treatment for the former empire than for random strangers. As well, these visa-free things are often reciprocal, and people from former British colonies are likely to want to go to Britain.

Comment: Just to be precise: The page you're linking to lists the visa conditions for British citizens and not for British passport holders.

Comment: @KateGregory Depends on how the decolonization went down. In any case, I don't really see that either, in practice.

Comment: I suppose, being dual British/American citizen then is even better.

Comment: @AleksG OTOH, there is a lot of overlap, maybe some other combinations are even more valuable!

Comment: @Relaxed agreed, however I only have US and British ones :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about politics

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not too sure about the “despite colonization” bit. I can't really see a pattern, one way or the other. Some ex-British colonies offer visas on arrival for British citizens (e.g. Kenya), some don't (e.g. India) and most treat [German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_German_citizens) or [French citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_French_citizens) in exactly the same way. And then for some reason, Luxembourgish and Finnish citizenships – but not British citizenship – are the only ones in Europe to enable a visa on arrival in India.

At the end of the day, the [source used by Wikipedia](https://www.henleyglobal.com/visa-restrictions/) ([full table](http://www.tamilnet.com/img/publish/2013/10/Global_Ranking_-_Visa_Restriction_Index_2013-08.pdf)) has British citizens tied with Swedes and Finns and not far above citizens from a host of other European nations, Australia, the US and Canada. So the small differences that do exist might simply be accidents and the main fact in all this is that citizens from rich nations generally have easier access to other countries, whatever their colonial history.

Explanations for that might include the fact that it's good for business and tourism or that these countries have more means to secure agreements through diplomacy, foreign aid, etc.

One glaring difference between UK and US citizens (lack of visa-free visit or at least visa-on-arrival for Brazil) might however be explained. I can't find an official source for that right now but I think Brazil has a strict reciprocity policy and only grants visa-free access to citizens of countries that do the same for Brazilian citizens. Brazilian citizens [can visit the UK without visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/brazil/tourism) but [not the US](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visa-waiver-program.html).

Comment: After recent changes, India allows VISA on arrival for US and others https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/tvoa.html, UK missed interestingly, but the full table pdf is hosted in your site?

Comment: the reason for India being strict on Brits is likely reciprocal. The UK is rather infamously strict on Indians these days (due in part to the large demand for UK visas from India admittedly)