# What countries allow the most visa free / visa on arrival entries?

Tags: passports, visas-on-arrival, visa-free-entry

[Why is the British passport the most valuable despite colonization?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/31379/4868) is a discussion of which passports allow the most visa-free or visa-on-arrival entries. That kinda has me wondering what the most open country is. ie. which country is the most universally easiest to get into, regardless of what country you're coming from.

Like just because UK visitors can get into a lot of countries without visa's doesn't necessarily mean that all their agreements are reciprocal and that just anyone can get into their country without a Visa. Or are visa free agreements always reciprocal?

Comment: There are several countries and territories with absolutely no restrictions on who is allowed to visit (and in some cases even permanently stay and/or work). Some of them are mentioned in the answers to the question I linked to.

Comment: The other question is relevant (although it mostly mentions microstates and some exotic territories) but it does not address the reciprocity aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreements tend to be reciprocal (although I would not be surprised if some weren't) but many countries also simply decide unilaterally to grant visa-free entry to citizens of other countries. You don't need an agreement for that.

For example, compare [the visa policy of Haiti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Haiti) (certainly a very open country, on paper) and [requirements for Haitian citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Haitian_citizens). While I don't know any ranking for that, it seems Haiti could be both one of the most open countries and one of those whose citizens suffer from the most restrictions (to the extent that Wikipedia's info is correct, of course). The [DRC is another contender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Congolese_citizens) (however, unlike Haiti, [it's not very open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Democratic_Republic_of_the_Congo)).

[Maldives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Maldives) and [Seychelles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Seychelles) do not require a visa to visit, from anyone.

Comment: *tend to be reciprocal* - Ummm...  Not necessarily the case...

Comment: @Karlson “tend” implies “not necessarily”, I would write “are” otherwise.