# What is the best passport for traveling?

Tags: visas, passports, international-travel, visa-free-entry

Which country's passport is the best for traveling? I mean no need visa to enter, allowed time to stay without visa, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the British passport the most valuable despite colonization?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31379/why-is-the-british-passport-the-most-valuable-despite-colonization)

Comment: [This document](https://www.henleyglobal.com/files/download/hvri/HP%20Visa%20Restrictions%20Index%20140728.pdf) has it all.

Comment: The VISA on arrival norms have been changed for India recently, though thats not the primary point here  http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-30241487

Comment: @neo that question was closed with no answers.  Not great to mark as a duplicate of if there's no answers :/

Comment: The passport of the country you're going to.

Comment: Michael Hampton - good answer :) In this case we need figure out how to get passports to each country where we go. It would be cool to make kind of traveler ID, which allow you go to any or almost any country for 30 days or around it. Even it require more careful person checkin and more expensive, but will make travel more comfortable.

Answer (score 5):

It depends a little on how you measure this, but if you're going on the passport that needs the fewest visas to travel, it's entirely possible to argue that the [British Passport ties with the US passport](http://www.doyouneedvisa.com/rank/passport/) in being able to travel freely to 168 countries or territories.

However, another list claims a [higher number for Britain - 173, tied with Finland and Sweden](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/travelnews/10928261/Britain-tops-list-of-worlds-most-powerful-passports.html), with the US, Denmark, Germany and Luxembourg in second place with 172.

The trouble with measuring it is that people have different definitions on what defines a 'country' or 'territory'.

Incidentally the second source comes from Movehub's page on this, and they have an [infographic](http://www.movehub.com/sites/default/files/filemanager/passport-power-fixed.png) on this too.

[image]

Comment: There is also the question of what exactly counts as "visa free access". For example the USA insists that the ESTA is "not a visa" but it certainly has a lot in common with other countries e-visas.

Comment: @PeterGreen Not really. E-Visas are actual documents that must be presented at immigration, whereas ESTA, as well as eTA and eVisitor, are essentially electronic passport registrations